# ReflectionException in Route.php line 339: Class App\Http\Requests\CreateTenantRequest does not exist in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, validation, request, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3. I am getting this error when I am trying to submit the form. I used laravelcollective/html. Here is my code:

routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('add-new-tenant', 'SuperAdmin\TenantController');

Route::resource('new-tenant', 'SuperAdmin\TenantController@store');
```

Controller:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdmin;

 use App\Tenant;

 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Requests\CreateTenantRequest;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TenantController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.superadmin.add-new-tenant');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\CreateTenantRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function store(CreateTenantRequest $request)
  {
    Tenant::create($request->all());

    return redirect('add-new-tenant');
  }

}
```

I have created a request to validate a form. The code is as follows:

app/Http/Requests/CreateTenantRequest.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Requests;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateTenantRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'tenant_company_name' => 'required',
        'tenant_name' => 'required',
        'tenant_email' => 'required|email'
        'tenant_domain' => 'required',
        'tenant_database' => 'required'
    ];
  }
}
```

I am getting this error when I am submitting the form.

```
 ReflectionException in Route.php line 339:
 Class App\Http\Requests\CreateTenantRequest does not exist
```

I know there is some problem in declaring **CreateTenantRequest** but please help me what I am missing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

It was just my fault and when I saw this I banged my head on the wall, I wasted 4 hours on this and didn't notice this. The only error was a missing **comma (,)** after

```
 'tenant_email' => 'required|email',
```

in CreateTenantRequest.php. Here it is:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'tenant_company_name' => 'required',
    'tenant_name' => 'required',
    'tenant_email' => 'required|email',
    'tenant_domain' => 'required',
    'tenant_database' => 'required'
   ];
 }
```

Thanks for the help and sorry it was my fault.

Answer (score 1):

It all looks OK to me. My guess is that `Requests` has not been added to your autoloader. The first thing to do whenever you get a message saying that `laravel` cannot find something you know is there, and can see you have correctly included in your classes, is to dump the autoloader:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I tried using composer dump-autoload but its throwing an error failed with return code 0 and generating message Generating autoload files. Can you help me with this?

Comment: It's difficult to debug composer issues without seeing the actual message and how your project is set up. In `laravel` composer uses`PSR-4` so it's worth checking that your `namespaces` match your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on @Aisha Kamran's answer. This error message happens when there's syntax error on your custom form request. Not really a helpful error message.